# Can you generate both OAS2 and OAS3 in the same project?

Tags: c#, api, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

Since my project is currently still running on OAS2 I was asking myself it was possible to run OAS3 in parallel to my generated OpenApi2.0.

[image: extract from my swagger]

I could imagine to have a second link there but instead of OAS2.0 with the newer OAS3.x

I had look into the Startup.cs which hosts my project configuration and it seemed to me as if it was either version 2 or version 3. Is there a possibility to generate both versions and show them in the UI?

Example code:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseSwagger(c =>
        {
            c.SerializeAsV2 = true;
        });

        app.UseSwagger(c =>
        {
            c.RouteTemplate = "/swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json";
        });

        app.UseSwaggerUI(
             options =>
             {
                 // build a swagger endpoint for each discovered API version
                 foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
                 {
                     options.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json", description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant());

                 }
                 
             });
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

As I posted this, I found the answer myself..

So basically I did this:

```
            app.UseSwagger(c =>
        {
            c.SerializeAsV2 = true;
            c.RouteTemplate = "/swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json";
        });

        app.UseSwagger(c =>
        {
            c.SerializeAsV2 = false;
            c.RouteTemplate = "/swagger/{documentName}/swaggerv3.json";
        });
```

By doing this you can also create new API versions specifically for OAS3:

```
                 foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
                 {
                     options.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json", description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant());
                     options.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swaggerv3.json", $"{description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant()} OAS3");
                 }
```

[image]
And with that I get both versions. I thought they would overwrite, but apparently not. Thanks for rubber ducking... :D